# How to fix UnicodeEncodeError with pyarmor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyarmor

OS: Windows 10
python version: 3.8.5
pyarmor version: 6.4.2

Tree:

```
│   .gitignore
│   main.py
│   README.md
│   requirements.txt
│
├───cogs
│   │   somefile.py
│   │   somefile.py
│   │   somefile.py
│   │   somefile.py
│   │   somefile.py
│   │   somefile.py
│   │   somefile.py
│   │   somefile.py
│   │   somefile.py
│   │   somefile.py
│   │
│   └───__pycache__
│           pyc files
│
└───__pycache__
        main.cpython-38.pyc
```

I want to obfuscate every python file in my folder. I have set encoding to utf-8 in VS code, and I have added `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` to the beginning of each python file. I am running `pyarmor -d obfuscate --recursive main.py` from main.py and it's giving me this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pyarmor.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyarmor\pyarmor.py", line 1447, in main_entry
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyarmor\pyarmor.py", line 1439, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyarmor\pyarmor.py", line 694, in _obfuscate
    encrypt_script(prokey, a, b, wrap_mode=args.wrap_mode,
  File "c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyarmor\utils.py", line 933, in encrypt_script
    f.write(''.join(lines))
  File "c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 177-178: character maps to <undefined>
```

In the pyarmor documentation they give [this](https://pyarmor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/questions.html#xxx-codec-can-t-decode-byte-0xxx) possible fix. I've done that and the error persists.

Comment: Please don't put your answer on your question, add your answer. and then you can accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
I have fixed this by using the [pyarmor webui](https://pypi.org/project/pyarmor-webui/)